# Работа для C# разработчика

Tags: работа

Я сейчас нахожусь в поиске работы и у меня стал вопрос, а в каком мне дальше направлении развиваться. 
Мой опыт это разработка СРМ системы на C# под WinForms, где то полтора года.
Смотрю я в сторону Java, но у меня под него нет опыта, кроме нескольких маленьких игр 2д. Где время разработки составило 3 месяца, и никакие фреймворки я там не использовал. 
Если посмотреть на .NET то это нужно его опять таки учить..
WinForms как то не очень востребован по вакансиям.
Android тоже нужно изучать...(хотя на него тоже разрабатывал игру).
Стоит ли мне сейчас тратить месяца 3 на джаву или же подучить .NET? Ну или что мне можно делать?

Comment: Зря вы инвестировали время в WinForms, WPF намного современнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эмм, а в чем проблема-то? За полтора года вы уже должны стать вполне квалифицированным программистом, прекрасно знать сам язык, на  хорошем уровне быть знакомым с .NET, иметь твердые навыки в ООП, разработке и даже иметь какие-то навыки проектирования. А потому я не вижу особой проблемы уйти с WinForms (если действительно нужно) на WPF, ASP.NET или куда-то еще. Смысл в том, что у вас за это время должен был появиться существенный базис, который не должен зависеть от конкретной технологии, а потому освоение в новой сфере из вышеуказанных - дело пары месяцев (может чуть больше, может чуть меньше).

Что касается Java - весьма сомневаюсь, что с C# стоит уходить на Java (или наоборот). Это два довольно близких по задачам и по духу, если можно так выразиться, языка. На рынке примерно одинаковое количемство вакансий, которые примерно одинаково оплачиваются. То есть говоря русским языком - хрен редьки не слаще.

И еще:

> Если посмотреть на .NET то это нужно его опять таки учить

а как вы умудрились не изучить его, полтора года просидев на WinForms?

Comment: тут я имел введу web.

Comment: @Костя вы не обижайтесь конечно, но если бы ко  мне пришел устраиваться человек, который полотора года работал программистом C#, но при этом умудряется путать .NET и ASP.NET, я бы его впросто выставил за дверь

Comment: Просто устал, вылетело с головы что это ASP.NET